# Dealing with doubly escaped unicode string

Tags: python, unicode, python-3.5

I have a database of badly formatted database of strings. The data looks like this:

```
"street"=>"\"\\u4e2d\\u534e\\u8def\""
```

when it should be like this:

```
"street"=>"中华路"
```

The problem I have is that when that doubly escaped strings comes from the database they are not being decoded to the chinese characters as they should be. So suppose I have this variable; `street="\"\\u4e2d\\u534e\\u8def\""` and if I print that `print(street)` the result is a string of codepoints `"\u4e2d\u534e\u8def"`

What can I do at this point to convert `"\u4e2d\u534e\u8def"` to actual unicode characters ?

Comment: Do you know how they got there? The answers below seem to be assuming that they're Python string literals (from eg `repr`) but they could just as well be JSON strings (use `json.loads`), or some other format that uses `\u` escapes but potentially has different edge cases. Picking the wrong format may result in more mangling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First encode this string as `utf8` and then decode it with `unicode-escape` which will handle the `\\` for you:

```
>>> line = "\"\\u4e2d\\u534e\\u8def\""
>>> line.encode('utf8').decode('unicode-escape')
'"中华路"'
```

You can then strip the `"` if necessary

Comment: Just use the eval function: `eval("\"\\u4e2d\\u534e\\u8def\"")` is `'中华路'`.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy You're absolutely right. I must have been thinking python 2, though I see the `python-3.5` tag now. This solution should work for either python 2 or 3 though which is nice (if not what OP was asking specifically)

Answer (score 3):

You could remove the quotation marks with [`strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) and [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) at every `'\\u'`. This would give you the characters as strings representing hex numbers. Then for each string you could convert it to `int` and back to string with [`chr`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#chr):

```
>>> street = "\"\\u4e2d\\u534e\\u8def\""
>>> ''.join(chr(int(x, 16)) for x in street.strip('"').split('\\u') if x)
'中华路'
```

Comment: Just use the eval function: `eval("\"\\u4e2d\\u534e\\u8def\"")` is `'中华路'`.

Answer (score 2):

Based on what you wrote, the database appears to be storing an eval-uable ascii representation of a string with non-unicode chars.

```
>>> eval("\"\\u4e2d\\u534e\\u8def\"")
'中华路'
```

Python has a built-in function for this.

```
>>> ascii('中华路')
"'\\u4e2d\\u534e\\u8def'"
```

The only difference is the use of `\"` instead of `'` for the needed internal quote.